# Is it possible to reverse engineer AES256?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes, cryptanalysis

Imagine I have this:

```
$cdata = AES_256($data, $pass);
```

AES_256 implements the [AES algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard).

If I know the content of `$cdata` and the content of `$data` and also have
the `AES_256()` code, can I reverse engineer and find `$pass`?

Comment: You're going to need alot of paper and pens

Comment: Just a matter of wording: Reverse engineering AES would give you the AES algorithm. You already know that algorithm. What you are asking is called "breaking AES".

Comment: Yes, of course, given sufficient time.  :-)

Comment: I found a related answer on [security.stackexchange.com regarding known-plaintext with AES](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5355/compute-the-aes-encryption-key-given-the-plaintext-and-its-ciphertext) which may be helpful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simple answer: NO.

This has been tested, and mentioned in the Wiki link.

> A related-key attack can break up to 9
>   rounds of 256-bit AES. A
>   chosen-plaintext attack can break 8
>   rounds of 192- and 256-bit AES, and 7
>   rounds of 128-bit AES, although the
>   workload is impractical at 2<sup>128</sup> -
>   2<sup>119</sup>.

Or put it another way: you have a better chance of being struck by lighting... on the same day you win the Lottery, than breaking it!

Comment: "break up to 9 rounds of 256-bit AES"
What is a "round" in this definition?

Comment: Block ciphers scrambles the message repeatedly using the same algorithm. A single "pass" of scrambling is called a "round". How many rounds are needed create a secure algorithm depends on how much a single round scrambles the input. AES-256 uses 14 rounds.

Comment: @Nuoji I get what a 'round' is for AES and in the context of an encryption algorithm but what does it mean when something says when "an attack can break up to *x* rounds..."?

Comment: This means, if you only use x rounds of the algorithm, there is an attack less complex than brute force to retrieve the plaintext.

Answer (score 13):

This is called a [known-plaintext attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack). A good cipher like AES should be immune to it, as the others explained.

Answer (score 4):

If `$pass` is actually a password and not a 256-bit key, you may be in luck.

While it is far from trivial to perform, a brute-force attack against a normal password is much faster than brute-forcing a 256-bit key.

So modify one of the many password-brute-forcing tools, and you have a attack that (depending on the strength of the password) might take weeks to several years - but that is fast compared to 3x10^51 years...

Answer (score 3):

Another quote, from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute_force_attack#Theoretical_limits):

> AES permits the use of 256-bit keys.
>   Breaking a symmetric 256-bit key by
>   brute force requires 2^128 times more
>   computational power than a 128-bit
>   key. A device that could check a
>   billion billion (10^18) AES keys per
>   second would require about 3 x
>   10^51 years to exhaust the 256-bit
>   key space.

Brute forcing when you know the original text might be faster but still, 3 x 10^51 years is a long time. Plus there's the problem of probably not having a device that can check a billion billion (10^18) keys/second.

**In short**: everything is possible, but this is not feasible in the world we are now living in.

Answer (score 2):

You could brute force it, but it would take a long time. As in decades or even longer. That's the point of encryption algorithms like AES.

Comment: The duration you are looking for is not "decades". It's more like "heat death of the universe".

Comment: @joeforker and in 20-30 years I'm sure we'll be laughing about how trivial it is to break AES 256 and current encryption uses megabyte keys to keep up with computers.

Answer (score 1):

AES, like all good crypto algorithms, doesn't rely on [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

In other words, there are no "secrets" in the code, so you having the code won't help you particularly.

Known plaintext is a separate issue, which I don't know much about so I'll leave that up to the other answerers.

Answer (score 0):

Of course not - the only approach is brute force.
Do you really think NIST is so stupid as to choose a cipher that is so easily cracked for a new standard?

Answer (score 0):

with the power of super computers the time to crash AES encryption with be dramatically shortened.... I heard...

Answer (score 0):

2x2^256 possible combinations is a lot to bruteforce. But bruteforcing is the only way. It would actually take about 3 decades. AES is the best Encryption possible right now I'd say. But that would only take that much time using a CPU. Because GPU's (Graphic Processing Units) are strictly math based, people have been making programs that only use the GPU to crack math based algorithms much more quickly than a CPU could. In other words AES might not last 3 decades. If only eternity codes were possible. Well looks like dynamic encryption may be the only way people can really hide their information in the near future.

Comment: Three decades?! You can't even *count* to 2^192 in three decades if you used the *entire output power of the Sun* with an *ideal* computer. ["If we built a Dyson sphere around the sun and captured *all* its energy for 32 years, without *any* loss, we could power a computer to count up to 2^192. Of course, it wouldn't have the energy left over to perform any useful calculations with this counter."](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/25392/28624) This means that it would take 59,029,581,035,870,565,171 decades with all that computing power just to *count to* 2^256.